# How many times SUM() will be calculated?

Tags: sql-server, database, aggregate-functions

I am practicing T-SQL, and I wonder how many times SUM() will be calculated in the following query:

```
SELECT
    DepositGroup,
    SUM(DepositAmount) AS TotalSum
FROM WizzardDeposits
WHERE MagicWandCreator = 'Ollivander family'
GROUP BY DepositGroup
HAVING SUM(DepositAmount) < 150000
ORDER BY SUM(DepositAmount) DESC
```

Will it be calculated every time I write `SUM(DepositAmount)`? Or it will be calculated once and it will return the result onwards? I am worried about how much resource it will require if it's calculated every time I call it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you are grouping over `DepositGroup` it will be calculated once for each distinct group only.

Comment: *The SQL Server query optimizer can combine repeated calculated values into a single Compute Scalar operator.* You can read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166126/does-sql-server-cache-calculated-values-in-a-query)

Comment: If you look at the query plan, you'll very likely see a Compute Scalar, followed by a Filter and a Sort. The Compute Scalar have a "name" like `Expr 1030`, and if you then look at the Filter and Sort, you;ll notice they are based on that expression; so it isn't recalculated.

Comment: Thank you! @Larnu, I am using DataGrip, and if I understand the plan, only sort is based on that expression. https://i.imgur.com/ojUmhOO.png

Comment: @Larnu - referencing an `Expr...` doesn't guarantee that it won't be re-evaluated, see https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be calculated once.

The only place a `SUM` can be calculated is inside an aggregate operator (either stream aggregate or hash aggregate).

If you look at the execution plan you will only see one aggregation operator. This will have a defined values property along the lines of below.

```
[ExprxxxX] = Scalar Operator(COUNT_BIG([YourDB].[dbo].[WizzardDeposits].[DepositAmount]))
[ExprxxxY] = Scalar Operator(SUM([YourDB].[dbo].[WizzardDeposits].[DepositAmount]))
```

There will then be a compute scalar operator to the left of the aggregate operator with an expression like

```
[ExprxxxZ] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [ExprxxxX]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [ExprxxxY] END)
```

To ensure the `SUM` returns `NULL` if `COUNT_BIG` was zero ([not possible in this case](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html) as it isn't possible for `GROUP BY` to emit a row for a group with no rows).

The filter (implementing the `HAVING`) and the sort (for the `ORDER BY`) will reference this `[ExprxxxZ]`.

There is [no guarantee](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html) whether or not the underling `CASE` expression will be just computed once and passed along or re-evaluated each time but in any event this is trivial. The bulk of the work is done by the aggregate operator and that is certainly only done once per group.